# App isnt responding due to service

Tags: android

I have implemented this service which starts on bootup. But after using this service my app isnt working. It shows dialog box "App isnt responding!" As soon as i remove this service, it works properly. What could be my mistake?

public class Service1 extends Service
{

```
DBHelper helper;
ArrayList<String> apps;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("Service1", "onCreate()");
    helper=new DBHelper(this);
    apps=new ArrayList<String>();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.e("Service1", "onStart() "+Integer.toString(startId));
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("Service1", "onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    Log.e("Service1","onstartcmd()");
    check();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
public void check()
{
    while(true)
    {
        apps=helper.daylocked();
        Log.e("Service1","check()");
        if(apps!=null)
        {
            Log.e("Service1" ,apps.toString());
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Service` runs on the `UI Thread`. With the infinite while loop you are actually preventing it to execute any operation but the while loop. You can switch to an `IntentService` that runs on a different `Thread`

Answer (score 0):

The `Service` runs on the `UI Thread`.

You either choose to start an `IntentService` or you create the background threads for your own service.

Check: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

Comment: Can u help me with any link with an example of the background thread?

Comment: Example of IntentService: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html